# TFS baseless merges - deleted and recreated target branch and baseless merge no longer works

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging

I have the following branches on my source control, based on the following needs:
We have multiple environments, but in this case the important ones are Test and Production. We have multiple concurrent projects that need to be developed by separate teams and tested in a single test environment when they are ready. When they are ready, they can be pushed to production (with additional testing in an integration environment as warranted). We cannot organize features into dedicated releases - they need to go out as the business wants them to.

So what we settled on structure-wise was a branch-per-environment plus feature branches and we just accepted we would be performing baseless merges into the Test branch. Not a big deal as we can just merge specific changesets to Test via the UI.

*$/Benefits/Source/Main* - trunk where we do production and/or integration deployments
*$/Benefits/Source/Test* - branch where we merge features into for primary testing
*$/Benefits/Source/Dev/LURE-7* - branched from trunk
*$/Benefits/Source/Dev/[other features]* - branched from trunk

I have a feature branch that was merged to Test successfully and tested. Unfortunately, the Test branch got severely messed up by a couple merges and we decided that simply deleting and recreating the Test branch would be the best approach. We deleted the Test branch and recreated it from Trunk.

I now need to re-merge my feature branch into Test and it would seem my feature branch is keeping a history of its baseless merges and thinks my changes are already in the target branch. I have verified that the specific file changes are not in there.

Essentially what's happening, when I select "specific changesets" in the first page of the Merge wizard, the next page doesn't show any changesets newer than the original branch.

**The history of my feature branch, see the changes after the branch:**
[image: The history of my feature branch]

**Page 1 of the merge wizard:**
[image: Page 1 of the wizard]

**Page 2 of the wizard, it doesn't see the 2 changesets after the branch:**
[image: Page 2 of the wizard]

**The history of my Test branch, you can see it was deleted and recreated:**
[image: The history of my Test branch, you can see it was deleted and recreated]
(6/27 I merged my feature branch, 7/5 I deleted and recreated the Test branch)

Comment: Does the new test branch have the same name and location as the old one?

Comment: Yep, which is why I assume everything is messed up. Assuming that's the problem, was hoping there was a magic button to make my feature branch realize.

Comment: correct, basically TFS has undone the delete and the old branch remains. You have 2 options, create the new test branch in a new location so the path is different. This is prefereable if you want to maintain the history of the old branch. If you're happy to lose the history, use `tf destroy` from the command line. This will nuke the test branch and it will be gone forever. Be careful!

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, even though I know TFS behaves this way, I always think delete really means delete.

Comment: In this case, the Test branch can be as ephemeral as I want it to be. No need to keep its history, it is just there so it can be a source location for test deployments.

Comment: Oh and if you want the credit for the answer, feel free to add an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a branch in TFS, it's really still there, just hidden. If you create a new branch with the same name / location then TFS will undelete the old branch.

The best approach is to either

1. Create a new branch with a new name / location. Do this if you want to maintain history of the old deleted branch
2. Use `tf destroy` from the command line. Use this if history isn't important. **Be careful with this command**. once it's gone the only way to get it back is from a backup of your TFS database.

Comment: tf destroy worked and I understand the wariness to use it. I think it's the right solution in my case since the branch is solely there to be a place to build and deploy specific features for test. We can always remerge features into it, or recreated it off the trunk.

Comment: Yeah, the warning was more for others that see this answer. `tf destroy` is pretty much unrecoverable so you want to be extra careful using it. If you want to bring back something after it has been destroyed you need to use the most recent database backup before the destroy command was run, so you may lose other work checked in after the backup was taken.